# Cucumber Tags: : How to Run more than 20 tags in Feature File

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I'm working on a project and there are 40 feature files to be executed using cucumber and java. I have included all the 40 tags in Test Runner but It was mentioned in a post that cucumber can't run more than 20 tags in a test runner. If this is true, can anyone let me know how I can run all the tags when I have more than 20.

[image: Sample Test Runner]

Comment: Run it and see if the restriction exists...

Comment: Ok I'll check and see

Comment: You are misusing tags. Consider changing your usage of tags. Perhaps you should ask another question explaining how you are using tags and look for alternative ways of working with Cucumber

Comment: if it doens't support more than 20 tags then create two runner class with 20 tags each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more common tag for all 20 tags in your feature file.
Give common tag while running from test runner.